# Httpwebrequest throws error when running in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am calling a Rest API URL via the `HttpWebRequest` / `HttpWebResponse` method using IDs that are already stored in a database table.

I am currently using a for each loop to iterate through each of the IDs fetched in a DataTable and then making a call to the Rest API URL and finally dumping the results into multiple tables.

The code runs well at times but sometimes randomly throws the below error :
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I have tried various things but not able to crack it, below is my code for reference.

```
foreach (DataRow drow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string uri2 = "http://myrestURL/Transaction/" + drow.ItemArray[0].ToString();
    HttpWebRequest req2 = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri2);

    req2.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    req2.Method = "GET";
    req2.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    req2.ContentLength = 0;
    req2.Accept = "application/xml,*/*";
    req2.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    using (HttpWebResponse resp2 = (HttpWebResponse)req2.GetResponse())
    {
        StringReader theReader;
        DataSet theDataSet;
        using (StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(resp2.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string message2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();
            theReader = new StringReader(message2.ToString());
            theDataSet = new DataSet();
            theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);

            DataTable dt = theDataSet.Tables["table1"];
            DataTable dt1 = theDataSet.Tables["table2"];
            DataTable dt2 = theDataSet.Tables["table3"];
            DataTable dt3 = theDataSet.Tables["table4"];

            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns["ID"].SetOrdinal(0);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                row["ID"] = drow.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            }

            dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns["ID"].SetOrdinal(0);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
            {
                row["ID"] = drow.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            }

            dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns["ID"].SetOrdinal(0);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt2.Rows)
            {
                row["ID"] = drow.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            }

            dt3.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt3.Columns["ID"].SetOrdinal(0);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt3.Rows)
            {
                row["ID"] = drow.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            }

            SqlConnection insertConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
            insertConn.Open();

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy1 = new SqlBulkCopy(insertConn))
            {                
                bulkCopy1.DestinationTableName = dt1.TableName;
                try
                {
                    bulkCopy1.WriteToServer(dt1);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a third-party API or it belongs to you or your company? Is it possible that they have a limit for requests made in a short period of time?

Comment: Your first step is to check with the owner of the API and see if they can verify that they are seeing your request and returning a 401.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Before you do anything I would highly recommend to do the following two things: 1) Separate your code into smaller chunks like : issue request, process response, save ids 2) use better naming than `req2`, `dt3`, `bulkCopy1`